# MySQL - Either or but not both with no duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

Table dailyemails

```
id | email            | direction | operation
---+------------------+-----------+-----------------------
1  | adrian@gmail.com | Incoming  | Received successfully
2  | adrian@gmail.com | Incoming  | Unsuccessful
3  | beth@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
4  | carl@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
5  | carl@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
6  | dave@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
7  | dave@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
8  | dave@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Unsuccessful
9  | ethan@gmail.com  | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
10 | ethan@gmail.com  | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
11 | george@gmail.com | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
12 | george@gmail.com | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
13 | george@gmail.com | Outgoing  | Unsuccessful
14 | hanna@gmail.com  | Incoming  | Received successfully
15 | hanna@gmail.com  | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
16 | jane@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
17 | jane@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
18 | jane@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Unsuccessful
19 | kyle@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
20 | kyle@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
21 | kyle@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Unsuccessful
22 | lucy@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Received successfully
23 | lucy@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
24 | lucy@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Unsuccessful
25 | lucy@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Unsuccessful
26 | matt@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Unsuccessful
27 | nate@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Unsuccessful
28 | pat@gmail.com    | Incoming  | Received successfully
29 | pat@gmail.com    | Incoming  | Received successfully
30 | pat@gmail.com    | Outgoing  | Unsuccessful
31 | ryan@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
32 | ryan@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
33 | ryan@gmail.com   | Incoming  | Unsuccessfully
```

Query -

```
SELECT * 
  from dailyemails 
 WHERE direction in ('Incoming', 'Outgoing')
   AND operation = 'Sent successfully' 
    OR operation = 'Received successfully'
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query and grab user emails where there is either 1 incoming email OR 1 outgoing email that has been 'Sent successfully' or 'Received successfully'.

To further clarify, if a user has 2 or more successful incoming emails or has 2 or more successful outgoing emails then those must be excluded. Also, if a user has 1 successful incoming email AND 1 successful outgoing email those must be excluded.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

You can test out the schema and SQL here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0e43d

So the end result I should get is this:

```
id | email            | direction | operation
---+------------------+-----------+-----------------------
1  | adrian@gmail.com | Incoming  | Received successfully
3  | beth@gmail.com   | Outgoing  | Sent successfully
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to write a SQL query ..."* - Where?

Comment: Your question is almost perfect but the part that you show some effort showing that you at least try something is missing...

Comment: @JorgeCampos

I've written down the SQL query that I've tried. Sorry was making several edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation on a set-within-sets question.  A good way to answer it is with `group by` and `having`.

```
select max(de.id), de.email, max(de.direction), max(de.operation)
from dailyemails de
where de.operation in ('Sent successfully', 'Received successfully')
group by de.email
having count(*) = 1
```

Some explanation.  The `where` clause limits the operations to the only two of interest.  The `having` clause specifies that there is only one match.

The `max()` in the `select` is not really doing anything.  Only one row is matching in each group (because of the `where` clause).  Hence, this is just pulling the other values out of the row.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I'm still not quite understanding why you would use max on non-integer values. I still get the correct result when I remove all maxes from the query.

Comment: As you use the `group by` clause, you cannot simply refer to a column, that is not contained in the grouping. Instead, you have to use a function to aggregate all values of that column within a single group into one result that can be selected. `max` gives the correct value that in this case, as you have ony one value anyway. `min` would have done the job too ;-)